# sql server job generated error

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have the following error when I execute a job:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

This is my query stored procedure executed in the stored procedure of the job:

```
Update   table1
    Set     Field1 = DurationComputeFunction(Customer_ID,Start_Date)
            , Event_DateStamp = GetDate()
    From    table1 
    WHERE   DateDiff(day,Start_Date,getdate()) < 90
```

this stored procedure compute a duration. It only needs the customer ID and a Start Date.

On the other hand, I note that the following query:

```
select cast('23/10/2014' as datetime)
```

returns also the same error using windows authentication but returns no error (2014-10-23 00:00:00.000) when it is executed in sql server authentication.

So I deduce that maybe the job is executed with windows authentication that's why the stored procedure (the query) generates an error.

Am I right??

IF yes is there any way to force the job to be executed with sql server authentication??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, it is advisable to use to set dateformat. You can do like following

```
set dateformat dmy
select cast('23/10/2014' as datetime)
```

Try checking this and I am sure it will work. The same error is with your stored procedure, you have to include SET DATEFORMAT DMY before Update statement.